# Change default font Nuxt 3 + Vuetify 3 project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

I have been Googling a lot but I can't seem to find the answer. I feel the problem often is that maybe no one uses the Nuxt 3 + Vuetify 3 combination yet?

I'm trying to add a custom default font. I have tried it via `nuxt.config.ts` the way I used to with Nuxt 2.

```
vuetify: {
    customVariables: ["~/assets/variables.scss"],
    treeShake: true,
  },
```

But it doesn't work.

I am currently using `plugins/vuetify.ts` to define the theme and colors. I feel it should be set in there. But I do not know how.

```
import { createVuetify, ThemeDefinition } from "vuetify";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";

import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";

const myTheme: ThemeDefinition = {
    dark: false,
    colors: {
        primary: "#HEXHEX",
    },
    variables: {}
};

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
        components,
        directives,
        theme: {
            defaultTheme: "myTheme",
            themes: {
                myTheme
            }
    },
    });

    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify);
});
```

The themes are working, but I don't know how to overwrite the default fonts/styles.
Anyone dealt with the same issue and managed to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved same issue by manually importing some CSS in the `nuxt.config.js`

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass', '@/assets/main.css'],
  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify'],
  },
  ...
})
```

and in your CSS file

```css
/* main.css */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url('./fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Ah, simple as that. This works. I do have to define the classes myself though. But is there also a way to overwrite the $body-font-family for example. Doing this gives me an error in the terminal: `Error: This variable was not declared with !default in the @used module` but when I look in the Vuetify _variables.scss I do see the !default flag

Answer (score 2):

You can change the font for Vuetify 3 by setting the `$body-font-family` variable.
This requires that you have set up Vuetify 3 and Nuxt 3 as described in the Vuetify documentation.

Currently most of the documentation can be found here: [SASS-variables](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/)

You will need a Vuetify plugin in nuxt:

```js
/* plugins/vuetify.ts */
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
import "vuetify/styles";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
    // Other Vuetify settings like icons go here
  })

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

Then in `nuxt.config.js` you can use this plugin like this

```js
/* nuxt.config.js */
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ['@/assets/global.scss'],

  modules: [
    async (options, nuxt) => {
      nuxt.hooks.hook('vite:extendConfig', config => config.plugins.push(
        vuetify({
          styles: { configFile: new URL('assets/settings.scss', import.meta.url).pathname }
        })
      ))
    }
  ],
  
  // Other Nuxt config can go here
})
```

You can define a font in `/assets/global.scss`:

```scss
// /assets/global.scss
// Optional global scss settings
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: url("OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And in `assets/settings.scss` you can change Vuetify SCSS variables:

```scss
// /assets/settings.scss
// Specific Vuetify settings
@use 'vuetify/settings' with (
    $utilities: false,
    $button-height: 40px,
    $body-font-family: 'Open Sans'
);
```

If you search in `/node_modules/vuetify` for `$body-font-family`, you can find some other variables to modify the Vuetify font.

Answer (score 2):

I use combination of Nuxt3 (v3.1.1) and Vuetify3 (v3.1.3) and I've managed to achieve change of font globally for Vuetify and it utilities classes like (.text-h3).

First I suggest to follow [this](https://codybontecou.com/how-to-use-vuetify-with-nuxt-3.html) tutorial to setup Vuetify + Nuxt and then apply [Treeshaking](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#automatic-treeshaking) guide for Nuxt to only dynamically import components you need. You should end up with `nuxt.config.js` looking something like below

```js
import vuetify from "vite-plugin-vuetify";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: [
    "vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass",
  ],
  build: {
    transpile: ["vuetify"],
  },
  modules: [
    async (options, nuxt) => {
      nuxt.hooks.hook("vite:extendConfig", (config) =>
        config.plugins.push(vuetify())
      );
    },
  ],
});
```

After you should create file `.scss` file where you going to provide new defaults for Vuetify.

```scss
// assets/vuetifyTheme.scss
$font: "arial", sans-serif;

@use 'vuetify' with (
  $body-font-family: $font,
);
```

Next, import `vuetifyTheme.scss` at the top of your `plugins/vuetify.ts`

```js
// plugins/vuetify.ts
import "@/assets/vuetifyTheme.scss";
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
       ssr: true,
    },
  });

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify);
});
```

Your app should now see 'arial' as default font for your typography.

[dev-tools-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtEgz.jpg)

I've also notice that you can override variables defined in [vuetify/packages/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/3f8f577b51a7bfe948a075903348b886246e637e/packages/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss) in that way.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: It is not working for me :(

Comment: After I've upgraded to version 3.1.5 my solution stopped working with an error ` Failed to resolve entry for package "vuetify". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.`

Comment: I fixed my issue after deep searches when I reached this issue: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/15412#issuecomment-1398110500 good luck!

Comment: Thanks for leaving a lead, I've also finally managed to apply custom variables but it now results in missing source maps warning in console and ridiculous long build time. Hopefully this will go back to normal soon. Please, let me know if you find some solid solution around it. I found open issue there https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/issues/290 with some temporary fixes

Comment: Yep it seems like there are several issues around. But at least it works, we can use it. Also looking forward for everything to come back to normal.